# How can I talk to my game-master about his self-insert character without offending him?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, problem-gm, gmpc

I have been in this long-term game where the group has been in a semi-railroaded adventure. However, there has been something that has been bugging me for a while.

The game-master has this person following us who is the father of the gods. He resurrects us when we get a party wipe or gives us quests, which made him appear as a typical NPC at first; however, as the game progressed, the guy has started appearing everywhere, watching us fight and occasionally mocking us while flaunting his powers that cannot be explained by the book (like stopping time for everyone except him and the group while also disabling all of the group's spells).

It has reached a point where several players along with me are disturbed by this character appearing everywhere and mocking us, or getting mad at us saying we owe him for doing something he was against and then sending us to the next quest with us having no choice but to obey him or risk his wrath. All the while, the game-master constantly states that we are free to follow any lead we want.

I am planning to talk to the game-master and ask him to dial back with that character a bit or something similar. I am afraid that he will take it as a personal insult, as he seems to really associate with the character; the character says what he (the GM) wants to say to the party, and speaks and acts the same way he does.

**How can I talk to the GM and tell him my problem with his character without actually offending him?**